# How do i put a limit on TimerTask rather than having it run forever?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using the timer utility to repeatedly post output of a code. Right now I have it set to repeat nonstop on a 1 second interval. How could I change this to instead repeat until a time limit set by the user is reached?

```
//Create a new timer
Timer timer = new Timer();
static int interval = 1000; //Interval of timer in milliseconds
//Set the timer to start in 1 second and to go every certain amount of  milliseconds.
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerClass.timertask, 1000, interval);
```

Comment: Place a exit condition in the `TimerTask`

Comment: You will need to know when the task was started and check on each iteration how much time has passed and then compare that to the timeout value

Answer (score 0):

As [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) has said; this can be achieved by using the [`TimerTask.cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel--) method from within your [`TimerTask.run`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#run--) method.

For example:

```
public class RunUntilInstantTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private final Instant stopTime;

    public RunUntilInstantTimerTask(final Instant stopTime) {
        this.stopTime = Objects.requireNonNull(stopTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do scheduled stuff...

        if (Instant.now().isAfter(this.stopTime)) {
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured there was some way to set a limit, but this is my first time using timer so I was a bit confused.